# Total from an expression in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have written an expression and added it to a calculated field:

=IIF(fields!date1.value

The calculated field now returns either 1 or 0.

I want to now get a total of all the 1's, but when I try and get a total: =count(fields!totals.value = 1) then it just totals every row in the report, e.g. the total counts the 0's as well.

Please can someone advise how to get get a total of just the 1's? - e.g., sift out the 0's?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, it is a SUM operation. In your tablix total field input the expression like "SUM(fields!totals.value = 1)"

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I did try that, and it says #Error. Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: Assume your calculated field name is "Cal", and your formula should be like "=IIF(Fields!Date1.Value="2015-01-01", 1, 0)". In your tablix your formula should be SUM(Cal).

Comment: My calculated field is called 'totals' and its formula is: =iif(fields!date1.value<iif(fields!date2.value IS NOTHING,today(),fields!date2.value),"1","0") - this works fine to get me a 1 or a 0 - it's just adding the 1's that's causing a headache.

Comment: If you are using SSDT for report development, you can expand error panel to see details. In your case I guess probably you put the calculation SUM(Total) into the details group. In the tablix you need to add a total row (outside of the detail group), then put the SUM(total) into this total row.

Comment: Sadly the error appears in the report page, so can't be expanded out. I thought maybe 'totals' was being read as text, not a number. I did add the total row outside the group, but to no avail. When I do a count, it duly counts all the rows, but nothing doing when it comes to sum. Thanks for your help - I'll muddle along and if I solve it I'll post something up here.

Comment: change the formula to "=iif(fields!date1.value<iif(fields!date2.value IS NOTHING,today(),fields!date2.value),1,0) ". Remove double quotation.